# Detect and stop user from leaving current page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation

I want to detect when a user tries to leave the current page and probably stop them from doing so in flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow,
You can achieve this by using the WillPopScope Widget.
Below is a code sample to achieve this.

```
WillPopScope(
          child: Container(),
          onWillPop: () {
            if (allowPop) {
              return Future.value(true);
            } else {
              return Future.value(false);
            }
          });
```

Where `allowPop` can be a variable you can use to check if to allow user to leave the page or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of `WillPopScope`.

```dart
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    // returning false will don't let screen pop.
    return false;
  },
  child: ... // Your Scaffold goes here.
);
```